# HTTPS on node.js issue

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am very new to Node and I'm trying to install a SSL certificate. Ordered one online and I got two files:

> domain.com.ca-bundle
>
> domain.crt

How should I go about installing the certificate on Node.js server?

After reading through [this guide](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9705/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-nodejs) I found that we need one more additional which is `private.key` so I'm trying to understand how to go about it.

I'd really appreciate any inputs on how to proceed. Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask.

**Environment:**
I run Debian 9 on my VPS with Node.js installed.

Comment: Do you use a reverse proxy for your app?

Comment: No, its just a regular node.js/react app.

Comment: Node has some docs on setting up an https server [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But it's saying self signed certificate.. But I got one but not sure how do I install it?

Comment: It says this can be used for both types of certificates, they just chose to use a self-signed one as an example. As far as I know, setting up the server to read from the certificate files is all the installation you need. A couple of Google searches related to "https for nodejs" turn up a bunch of results including other stackoverflow questions which may be helpful to you

Comment: I use `letsencrypt` to generate certificates and `nginx` to handle the SSL portion, but both of my certificate files are in the `.pem` format so I'm not entirely sure what you need to do to/with your files to achieve this